# Atom 230 + 2GB RAM datastore for small server = 64 bit or 32 bit debian

Tags: linux, debian, raid

would you recommend me for small debian linux with small apache, small mysql and primary datastore with SW RAID 5 just 32bit debian or rather 64bit and why?
I have only 2 GB of RAM, so could that be enough. (it will be only CLI debian without Xserver, GUI and so on!)

Comment: It's 2013 and people are still deploying servers with 2GB of RAM? My phone has twice that amount of RAM...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are **some** pros and cons if you use 64-bit.

*Pros:*

- native CPU instruction set,
- some integer counters in Linux will be 64-bit size, like those you see on /proc/net/dev which restart from 0 when reaching max value (quite early if using 32-bit),
- some programs will run significantly faster if they make use of 64-bit calculation (usually compression and crypting are among those).

*Cons:*

- program binaries are usually a little bigger to store on disk,
- running programs may use slightly more RAM.

If your not using an embedded system, nor have special needs, I would go for 64-bit. Afterall, 32-bit is getting old now, and 64-bit is the future/present...

Answer (score 1):

According to the Intel documentation your processor can handle a 64 bit OS. I don't think the only advantage of 64 bit over 32 bit is raising the RAM limit from ~3.5GB. Therefore unless you are aware of a particular reason not to use the 64 bit version I would reccomend the x86_64.

http://ark.intel.com/products/35635/Intel-Atom-Processor-230-512K-Cache-1_60-GHz-533-MHz-FSB

Answer (score -1):

In my experience 32-bit uses less memory. Once the install was complete I had 8MB used, which is very impressive. I think it was about 16MB with a fresh 64-bit install. So if memory is your main concern, go for 32-bit; I can't judge performance as it requires real testing.